# Redirect from an iframe?

Tags: html

I have some forms embedded in a WordPress site, which when submitted are supposed to redirect to a new page in the site, however the redirect is being seen as a pop up and is being blocked.

This is the embed code for the form

`<script src="https://static.airtable.com/js/embed/embed_snippet_v1.js"></script><iframe class="airtable-embed airtable-dynamic-height" src="https://airtable.com/embed/shrYHPNzxTKSigU6t?backgroundColor=orange" frameborder="0" onmousewheel="" width="100%" height="2149" style="background: transparent; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></iframe>`

I have done some research and seen the use of  target="_top" will redirect the parent window but as I don't have access to the redirect itself I am not sure where to add this.

My question really, is, is this possible?

Comment: If it were me I'd look at using custom PHP code and write a form using HTML & javascript fetch.. but that's just because I'm familiar with that. Maybe give some more background info. Did you recently move this site from a different domain, etc?